# Deserialize JSON object in C#

Tags: c#, json

I want to get manuscript summary from PubMed. The content of each summary is in a JSON with the following format. The "29498802" is a unique ID, and it is different for each manuscript.

```
{
   "header":{
      "type":"esummary",
      "version":"0.3"
   },
   "result":{
      "uids":[
         "29498802"
      ],
      "29498802":{ 
       "uid":"29498802",
           "pubdate":"2018 Mar 2",
           "epubdate":"2018 Mar 2",
        ... 
    }
   }
}
```

I use Newtonsoft.Json in C# to deserialize the JSON to an class:

```
var summary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Summary>(stringResult);
```

My Summary class is as follows:

```
public class Summary
{
    [JsonProperty("header")]
    public Header header { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("result")]
    public Result result { get; set; }

}

public class Result
{
    [JsonProperty("uids")]
    public List<string> uids { get; set; }

    public Dictionary<string, PubMedId> content { get; set; }
}

public class PubMedId
{
    [JsonProperty("uid")]
    public string uid { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

I was able to extract "header (type and version)", "uids", but "content" is always null. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your content isn't a dictionary and you don't got a PubMedId in your 'content' dictionary. If you had that, you would have had an other JSON object in it. {} sorry that I can't help you out with an example code. I'm on my phone right now.

Comment: I assume { "uid":"29498802", "pubdate":"2018 Mar 2", "epubdate":"2018 Mar 2", ... } is the value of the Dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

```
        var summary = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Summary>(text);
        var resultjO = JObject.Parse(text).Value<JObject>("result");

        var pubdAsJObject = resultjO.Value<JObject>(summary.result.uids[0]);
        var pubMed = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PubMedId>(pubdAsJObject.ToString());
```

Comment: i would wrap with `foreach` and change `summary.result.uids[0]` to the item from the `foreach` loop